# Calculation of standard deviations for regression coefficient standardization when intercept is not present

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, standardization

I took the code of function `lm.beta::lm.beta` in R and wrote it in this way to be more understandable (and commented the lines I'm not interested in):

```r
std_coeff <- function(object) {

    # if (!"lm" %in% attr(object, "class")) {
    #     stop("object has to be of class lm")
    # }

    mat_X <- as.matrix(model.matrix(object))
    mat_Y <- as.matrix(model.frame(object)[, 1])

    intercept_present <- attr(attr(object$model, "terms"), "intercept")

    ss_fun <- function(x) {
        sqrt(sum((x - mean(x, na.rm = T) * intercept_present)^2, na.rm = T))
    }

    # object$standardized.coefficients <- 
        coef(object) * apply(mat_X, 2, ss_fun) / apply(mat_Y, 2, ss_fun)

    # attr(object, "class") <- c("lm.beta", "lm")
    # 
    # return(object)
}
```

Function `ss_fun` calculates roots of sum of squares $\sqrt{\sum{(x_i - \overline{x} \cdot intercept\_present})^2}$ (that are standard deviations without dividing by sample size) of each variable. Hence, `apply(mat_X, 2, ss_fun)` represents $\sim \sigma_X$ (standard deviations of each independent, X, variable), and `apply(mat_Y, 2, ss_fun)` represents $\sim\sigma_Y$ (of dependent variable Y). Variable `intercept_present` is an indicator of intercept presence (0, 1), and it suppresses mean centering in formula of "standard deviations" if intercept is not present (`mean(x, na.rm = T) * intercept_present`).

Why is this indicator `intercept_present` needed? I.e., what is the theoretical basis to calculate standard deviation differently if intercept is not present?

The syntax to use `lm.beta::lm.beta()` when intercept is not present (notice part `+ 0`):

```r
lm_2 <- lm(Volume ~ Height + Girth + 0, data = trees)

coef(lm_2) # Regular coeffs
    #>     Height      Girth 
    #> -0.4773192  5.0440083

coef(lm.beta::lm.beta(lm_2))  # Standardized coeffs
    #>    Height     Girth 
    #> -1.063341  2.004465
```

Comment: In a model without an intercept, what would justify mean centering?

Comment: Are you talking about model $Y=\beta X +\epsilon$, where $X$ and $Y$ are standardized by (minus mean and divided by SD)?

Comment: I clarified my question. I ask, why standard deviations are calculated differently, if intercept is not present.